# mysql Update Statement depending on number of checkbox checked

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, checkboxlist

**Problem statement:**

- I have a form with multiple checkbox Fields, i have validated it so
  user can select maximum 9 checkbox and atleast 1 with jquery.
  [image: Form with Multiple Checkbox]
- I collect the Form checked values using Post method.
- i have mysql table with 12 columns.
  [image: Mysql Table Image]
- first 3 columns are "id", "rollnum", "selectStatus"
- Through session variables created during Login, i get roll number of student. So i can Run Update Query on particular row.
- **Question:** How do i Update those 9 subject columns according to user checked inputs. Note : i stored those checked input field values in an array.
- **Code**

  ```
  <form action="index.php" id="form-3" method="post">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="ucs303">UCS303 Operating Systems
      <input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="ucs406">UCS406 Data Structures and Algorithms
      <input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="uec401">UEC401 Analog Communication Systems
      <input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="uec612">UEC612 Digital System Design
      <input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="uec307">UEC307 Electromagnetic Field Theory & Trans Lines
      <input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="uec502">UEC502 Digital Signal Processing
      <input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="uec510">UEC510 Computer Architecture
      <button type="submit" name="year-3-submit">Submit Selection</button>
  </form>
  <?php
      if(isset($_POST['year-3-submit'])){
          if(!empty($_POST['year-3-checkbox'])){
              $subjectCheckList = array();
              $subjectCheckList = $_POST['year-3-checkbox'];
          }
      }
  ?>
  ```
- It depends on user how many checkbox is selected.
- I donot know how to write UPDATE sql query which updates values of number of columns == size of array.

*for example:
User 1 has selected 3 checkbox and submitted form, we have array of size 3 and UPDATE 3 columns of table.
User 1 has selected 6 checkbox and submitted form, we have array of size 6 and UPDATE 6 columns of table.*

- I donot want to write 9 switch case statements for all possible sizes
  of array. Any idea? please?

Comment: simply loop over the array and prepare your update query using the loop by concatenating the sql string

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya , it would be of much great help if you talk with sample code/snippet.

Comment: As an example:
`$sql = "Update table SET ";
foreach ($post_values as $post) {
    $sql .= $post['field'] . " = " . $post['value'];
}`

Comment: Also, give your query which you have created for one of the case(s), I will modify it to make it generic

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i will write here in a minute, post it as answer and i will mark it

Comment: //Assuming user has Checked 9 feilds
    
        $sql = "UPDATE subjectmaster SET substatus=1, sub1=$subjectCheckList[0],sub2=$subjectCheckList[1],sub3=$subjectCheckList[2],sub4=$subjectCheckList[3],sub5=$subjectCheckList[4],sub6=$subjectCheckList[5],sub7=$subjectCheckList[6],sub8=$subjectCheckList[7],sub9=$subjectCheckList[8] WHERE rollno= '$rollnumber'";

Comment: i donot know how to put code in comments, please bear with raw text code

Comment: Ok no worries. I am putting up an answer soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179265/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-krupesh-anadkat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP's comments, you can make the code generic as follows:

```
// Check if atleast one subject has been selected
$selectedSubjects = array_filter($subjectCheckList);

// If no subject selected
if (empty($selectedSubjects)) {
    $sql = "UPDATE subjectmaster 
            SET substatus = 0 
            WHERE rollno = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($rollnumber) . "'";
} else {
    // Initialize the sql string
    $sql = "UPDATE subjectmaster 
            SET substatus = 1 ";

   $i = 1;
   foreach ($subjectCheckList as $subject) {
       $sql .= ", sub" . $i . " = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($subject) . "' ";
   }

   $sql .= " WHERE rollno = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($rollnumber) . "'";
}
```

Also, note the use of `mysqli_real_escape_string`. It helps in preventing SQL injection. For better ways to prevent SQL injection, you may check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. Please upvote my question, Someone downvotes it on purpose everytime i put a question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Well, 1st of all it is not clear what should be the default valued for each column.
Since your MySQL columns are set by numbers (sub1, sub2, etc) then your form should represent them accordingly, with the proper value. for example:

```
<input class="form-check-input" name="year-3-checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

This way, you can loop easily and update the table (I assume the sub columns are TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL) :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['year-3-submit'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['year-3-checkbox'])){
            $subjectCheckList = array();
            $query = "UPDATE table SET ";
            foreach ($_POST['year-3-checkbox'] as $key => $value) {
              $query .= " sub" . $value . " = 1, " 
            }
            $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
        }
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps
Guy

Comment: i need the values as the subject code, it cant be changed under any circumstances

Comment: then you should store them in some sort of a keys table, something like: headers **subs, values** and values like __sub1,ucs303__ etc

Comment: I got the answer most suitable for me, thankyou for your help.

Comment: @krupeshAnadkat
The accepted answer is good, but the de-normalised subN columns are still bad database design for entirely different reasons.

Check out "normal form" for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_filter, array_combine and array_slice.

```
<?php

$subs = [':sub1',
         ':sub2',
         ':sub3',
         ':sub4',
         ':sub5',
         ':sub6',
         ':sub7',
         ':sub8',
         ':sub9'
];

// use $dataFromForm = array_filter($_POST['year-3-checkbox'])

$dataFromForm = ['11111',
                 '222222',
                 '3333333'];

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '*******');


$sql = 'UPDATE test SET sub1 = :sub1, sub2 = :sub2, sub3 = :sub3, sub4 = :sub4, sub5 = :sub5, sub6 = :sub6, sub7 = :sub7, sub8 = :sub8, sub9 = :sub9';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array_combine(array_slice($subs, 0, count($dataFromForm), $dataFromForm)));
```